# How to install python3.4-pip in FreeBSD 10.1?

Tags: installation, freebsd, python, pip

I searched in the ports and can't find a pip installation package other than the pip for python27 `py27-pip-6.1.1`.

Which way is the best for installing pip for python 3.x in FreeBSD 10.1?

Or is it [included](http://www.reddit.com/comments/1oz5ve) in python 3.4 and and I just haven't figured out how yet?

Answer (score 17):

With Python 3.4 and later, you can use the `ensurepip` module to install pip on FreeBSD and elsewhere.

```
python3.4 -m ensurepip
```

should install pip as pip3.4.

Comment: after that use `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip` to get to (currently) v9.0.1

Answer (score 4):

Sadly there doesn't seem to be pip integrated in python3.4 in the FreeBSD ports.

So I had to install pip like discribed [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html)

Comment: I also had to install pip as described there.  But at least it worked after that!

Comment: Same situation on Debian Wheezy when installing python3.4 from the sid. Absolutely no pip coming with it. I had to use the `get_pip.py` script.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.4+ contains `pip` by default and need no additional packages to be installed.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

> pip included with Python
>
> Python 2.7.9 and later (on the python2 series), and Python 3.4 and
>   later include pip by default [1], so you may have pip already.

https://docs.python.org/3/installing/

> Python only started bundling pip with Python 3.4. For earlier
>   versions, pip needs to be “bootstrapped” as described in the Python
>   Packaging User Guide.

Comment: could you clarify how it is used than? I can't find any pip / pypip / pythonpip commands....?

Comment: I'm not familiar with python and don't know how to use it or pip. I've just mention that there is no separate package for pip since 3.4 released.

Comment: @Kondybas Please provide a link to the evidence that this is true.

Comment: @mareoraft I've edit my answer.

Comment: I think this quote from the docs should also be included in the answer: "Starting with Python 3.4, pip is included by default with the Python binary installers".  I did not have pip installed on my FreeBSD 10.1 server.  I installed python3 via pkg.  Perhaps pkg didn't install it directly from the binary installers?

Comment: 2016, FreeBSD 11, Python 3.5 - pip is still not installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

`cd /usr/ports/devel/py-pip && make FLAVOR=py36 all install`